# Стиль для TabItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

Хочу сделать что-то вроде таких кнопок вместо стандартных `TabItem` в `TabControl`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переопределяю в стиле `ContentControl` для `TabItem`, но не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы ширина прямоугольника была чуть больше текста и вкладки находились рядом друг с другом? 
При таком стиле `TabItem` просто растягиваются на все окно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

xaml:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0099ff"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#0080d6"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                           Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                           Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightOffsetConverter}}"
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                           RadiusX="3"
                                           RadiusY="3"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                           Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                           Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightOffsetConverter}}"
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                           RadiusX="3"
                                           RadiusY="3"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                           Foreground="White"/>

                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                                           Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                           Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightOffsetConverter}}"
                                           Fill="White"
                                           RadiusX="3"
                                           RadiusY="3"
                                           Opacity="0.1"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1"
                                           Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                           Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightOffsetConverter}}"
                                           Fill="Black"
                                           RadiusX="3"
                                           RadiusY="3"
                                           Opacity="0.1"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

converter:

```
public class HeightOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value - 2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что означает «чтобы вкладки находились рядом друг с другом»? А сейчас как они находятся?

Comment: @VladD, Имел ввиду, чтобы они находились рядом в строку, а не в столбик, как на второй картинке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,3,0" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabControl}, Path=Padding}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#584a97"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultColor" Color="#584a97" />
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkColor" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DefaultColor}, 
                                                 Converter={StaticResource ColorLightConverter}, ConverterParameter=DARK}" />
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColor" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DefaultColor}, 
                                                 Converter={StaticResource ColorLightConverter}, ConverterParameter=LIGHT}" />
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectColor" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DefaultColor}, 
                                                 Converter={StaticResource ColorLightConverter}, ConverterParameter=SELECT}" />

                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                            <Border x:Name="body"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    CornerRadius="5">

                            <Grid Height="50" x:Name="grid">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Border x:Name="textBorder"
                                        Grid.Column="0" 
                                        Padding="25,0"
                                        CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
                                        Background="#0FFFFFFF">

                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header, Converter={StaticResource StringUpperConverter}}"
                                                   Foreground="White"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                </Border>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="iconGrid">
                                    <Border Background="Black"
                                            Opacity="0.1"
                                            CornerRadius="0,5,5,0">
                                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                                   </Border>
                                   <Image Source="Resources/setting.png" Height="30" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            </Border>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="body" Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background,
                                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                                                Converter={StaticResource ColorLightConverter},
                                                                                ConverterParameter=LIGHT}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="body" Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background,
                                                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                                                    Converter={StaticResource ColorLightConverter},
                                                                                    ConverterParameter=SELECT}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="body" Property="RenderTransform">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.93"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter TargetName="body" Property="RenderTransform">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <TranslateTransform Y="2"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

code-behind:

```
    public class StringUpperConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class ColorLightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush br = value as SolidColorBrush;

        float coef = 0;

        if (parameter != null)
        {
            switch (parameter.ToString().ToUpper())
            {
                case "DARK":
                    coef = 0.8F;
                    break;
                case "LIGHT":
                    coef = 1.4F;
                    break;
                case "SELECT":
                    coef = 1.6F;
                    break;
                default:
                    coef = 1.1F;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return Common.ChangeLightness(br.Color, coef);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Common
{
    public static Color ChangeLightness(Color color, float coef)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)(color.R * coef), (byte)(color.G * coef),
        (byte)(color.B * coef));
    }
}
```