# Биндинг SolidColorBrush

Tags: wpf, xaml

Как привязать цвет кисти к элементу?

Делаю так, но не работает:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush  x:Key="DefaultColor" Color="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Ellipse Fill="{StaticResource DefaultColor}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button1" Background="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает вот так (с исправленным конвертером: он должен возвращать `SolidColorBrush`, а не `Color`):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorLightConverter"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Name="E" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter
                            TargetName="E" Property="Fill"
                            Value="{Binding Background,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                            Converter={StaticResource ColorLightConverter},
                                            ConverterParameter=LIGHT}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

По каким-то причинам `Setter` не хочет принимать `TemplateBinding`, но вместо него можно сделать `Binding` к `TemplatedParent`, что практически то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.

Comment: @maxwell: Вот и хорошо. Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate>
               <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Это понятно, но как забиндить именно кисть?

Comment: @maxwell, забиндить на что? я как понял вы хотите задать фон у кнопки с переопределенным шаблоном.

Comment: Это просто пример. Я хочу, чтобы в кисти хранился цвет определенного элемента. В данном случае цвет кнопки.

Comment: @maxwell, чтобы потом задать Fill?

Comment: @maxwell: Так вам нужен цвет или кисть? Что должно быть в VM?

Comment: @VladD, Нужна кисть, чтобы на основании этой кисти сделать более светлые кисти, которыми в свою очередь будет закрашиваться элемент при срабатывании триггера `IsMouseOver`. Если же работать в триггере со свойством элемента `Background` напрямую, то элемент будет все светлее и светлее.

Comment: @maxwell: То есть вы хотите менять создавать более светлые кисти на лету? Покажите, как вы хотите использовать кисть. (Ну и то, что триггер не отскакивает, это странно, может быть, вы что-то делаете не так?)

Comment: @VladD, Я хотел бы хранить светлые кисти в xaml, которые становятся светлее с помощью конвертера. Так можно ли прибиндить кисть?

Comment: @maxwell: А почему не `TemplateBinding` через конвертер?

Comment: @VladD, Доделываю пример по ссылке. Если делаю привязки в триггере через `TemplateBinding`, то возникает ошибка.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596433/222188

Comment: @maxwell: Для начала, ваш конвертер неправильный. Вы должны возвращать `SolidColorBrush`, а не `Color`.

Comment: @VladD, Исправил конвертер, но все равно в триггере возникает исключение в этой строке `<Setter TargetName="body" Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorLightConverter}, ConverterParameter=LIGHT}"/>`

Comment: @maxwell: Окей, разобрался. Сейчас напишу ответ.